# Install mod_auth_openidc CJOSE package not found

Tags: apache, mod-auth-openidc, openid-connect

I'm trying to use mod_auth_openidc the product proposed by ZmartZone (https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc )
I'm working on  "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)"
When i started to install packages, i found that "CJOSE" package does not exist.
Can you please help ? and if any one of you have already installed this product can explain to me how to proceed.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download binary packages for both `mod_auth_openidc` and `cjose` from the releases page: https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases/